# Mode in which system programs are executed

Tags: operating-system

I think that i get what system programs are, but i would like to understand why exactly they are executed partly in User mode and partly in Kernel mode.

Since computer software designed to provide services to other software, i thought that they may run entirely in kernel mode. In what casses they run in user mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the kernel mode and user mode level exists to prevent user software from damaging the system and its features.

how the user mode performs low level instructions?

ans - using system calls

a user-mode program can switch into kernel mode,but have no control over the instructions which will be performed in kernel mode.
so the only way this could happen is using system call, which interface used by User Mode to talk with low level resources (hardware).

The only exception is when a process uses ''ioperm'' system call. In this case a device can be accessed directly by 
User Mode process (IRQs cannot be used).

during the process ,

The user-mode program places values in registers, or creates a stack frame with arguments, 
to indicate what specific service it requires from the operating system. then performs the trap instruction.

Immediately, the CPU switches to kernel mode, and jumps to instructions at a fixed location in memory.

trap instruction or system call handler, read the details of the requested service + arguments, and then
perform this request in kernel mode.

finally With the system call done, the operating system resets the mode 
to user-mode and returns from the system call.